# Angular UI Select not showing up the selected element in dropdown (IE 11)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, internet-explorer, angular-ui-select

I am having issue with the dropdown populated using UI select not    able to show the element which had been selected earlier. This issue    is only coming in IE11, I tried checking the same with the demo of Angular UI select and unfortunately it has the same issue too.

Below is the screenshot of the issue in IE11 , I had selected "natasha" from dropdownlist and once I try to open it back again it would not show the same in dropdownlist as highlighted.

[image: Angular UI select Issue on select]

This is the same issue I am facing in my project, please let me know if there is any solution for the same. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ui-select-match  >         
        {{$select.selected.caption}}
      </ui-select-match>
```

change your code to below as walk around

```
 <ui-select-match  >         
        <span data-ng-bind="$select.selected.caption"></span>
      </ui-select-match>
```